# Steps to setup Email workflow using Service Tasks - Email component in JBPM5

Tags: jbpm, drools-guvnor

I am using Drools guvnor web designer. I want to send an e-mail in my process. There is a service task node, which is called "E-mail", but I'm not sure how to configure to make it work. Could you please provide me an example or describe a simple way to do this?

I have access to local exchange server.
Kindly provide me the information how to configure Email properties like Assignments, DataInputSet and DataOutputset ?
How to configure or link exchange server to Email service task node?